# says rather more than is strictly certain

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> But some care is needed in using Descartes' argument. 'I think,
>   therefore I am' **says rather more than** is strictly certain. It might
>   seem as though we were quite sure of being the same person today as we
>   were yesterday, and this is no doubt true in some sense.

[Problems of Philosophy - Bertrand Russell, Chapter II]

What does "says rather more than" mean? I don't understand that expression. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: It could mean that "it does have more deep meaning than what you assume when you hear it. Therefore, you should contemplate it and be careful about when you use it."

Comment: I don't understand why the author used two verbs there "says" and "is". Could I understand the sentence as: It is stricky certain that "I think, therefore I am" says rather more than?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "rather" means "to a somewhat large degree", as in "It is rather warm today." In other words,

> 'I think, therefore I am' says **somewhat more than** is strictly certain.

The sentence means that Descartes' quote makes a claim that exceeds what is definitely true.

It could also mean (as Mrt commented) that the quote has a deeper implied meaning than what the words literally express.

Comment: Does "'I think, therefore I am' says rather more than is strictly certain" have the same meaning as "'I think, therefore I am' says rather more than what is strictly certain". I am confused because the sentence has two verbs ("says" and "is")

Comment: @TrungstXVII Yes, that is what it means.